# Does a city by a lake count as coastal for the Lighthouse?

Tags: civilization-6

The Lighthouse building in the Harbour says it gives +2 housing for cities adjacent to Coast. Does this include cities built beside a Lake tile (but not beside an ocean Coast tile)?

Comment: The lighthouse only provides for cities which it is built in. Did you build the lighthouse on a lake tile?

Comment: @Wouter Yes. The city borders a Lake tile, built a Harbour on that Lake tile, and built a Lighthouse in that Harbour. Will it get the +2 housing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes: As of November 2022 a city by a Lake tile will receive the +2 bonus housing from a Lighthouse

Just thought I'd update this because I encountered this issue again and found my own question as the top result :)

As of November 2022, it seems that Lighthouses DO in fact count cities adjacent to lakes for the bonus housing. This is explicitly stated in the wiki: https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Lighthouse_(Civ6) and seems to be true in the game I just played as well.

I did think it used to be different, but I'm not sure, and looking through the changelogs there doesn't seem to have been a lighthouse change, so I may have misremembered. But now you know!

Answer (score 3):

**Update: This answer is obsolete since November 2022.**

<strike>Unlikely!</strike>

Coast is a tile type in Civ 6 that you can check by hovering over the tile.  Coast tiles are usually found in between Ocean and land tiles, not Lake and land tiles. Lake tiles are typically adjacent to land or other Lake tiles.

However, depending on the map type, small oceans can be generated that behave and look like multi-tile lakes. This has happened to me on Fractal maps.

So, you need a real Coast tile adjacent to the city to get the +2 housing. Check the tile type by hovering over it.